# Oh God! Troubleshooting tag!

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

Yeah, there's a [troubleshooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag... OMG... I don't have anything else to say :(

Comment: I used that tag once because it was a question like "I have this problem and I have no idea what to do now". What is a better tag for a case like that?

Comment: @Galgalesh flag it as unclear. If they have no idea what is going on, we less.